# Big O complexity estimate

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

```
    int i,j;
    int n=(some value);
    int B=1000;
    for (i=B;i<=n;i++)
    {
     j=3*i;
     while(j<=n)
         {
          j++;
           for(i=1;i<=B;i++)
              {
                 printf("%d",i);
               }
          }
      }
```

So to determine the Big O of this triple nest loop, my approach is that the first loop O(n), while the second loop is O(n/3) and the third loop is O(1) as its independent of n. so the total complexity is O(n^2)?

Comment: Have you searched for this topic on stackoverflow? Seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: Oh really? Is there a duplicate?

Comment: This code will not terminate for larger values of n, because the inner loop changes the same variable `i` that is used for the outer loop. The inner loop always leaves `i = B+1`. It doesn't make sense to talk about the time complexity of an algorithm which does not terminate.

Comment: hmm. so theres no time complexity for this?